# How to call Tor browser using Selenium using Java?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, java

How to call Tor browser using [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) testing framework using Java?

I have downloaded Tor and I have started IDE with Selenium JARs included.

I want to open Tor browser using selenium with Java and want to work on web URL.

Comment: Just to be sure: You have downloaded **Tor Browser Bundle** and you are asking about the Tor Browser from the bundle?

Comment: Similar question on Stack Exchange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978074/using-selenium-webdriver-with-tor-browser-bundle

Comment: Tor Browser Bundle Test Suite has running Python code that does what you want: https://gitweb.torproject.org/boklm/tor-browser-bundle-testsuite.git/tree/HEAD:/selenium-tests

Answer (score 5):

Tor Browser is essentially Firefox, with a couple of patches. I don't think that the patches would affect the use of Selenium when compared to normal Firefox.

The [Selenium documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) shows how to create a Firefox based WebDriver project.

The [FirefoxDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) in particular can take parameters to the location of Firefox, and the profile to use. You should update these to point to the TorBrowser. The *useExisting* flag looks promising for once you've started the Tor Browser Bundle.

I haven't tested any of this, but I expect this is enough to point you in the right direction. I expect someone else will come along and contribute a more verbose answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remote-control the Tor Browser, have a look at [Marionette from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette). It is built into the Tor Browser (and every other current Firefox). You **enable it on the command line** by calling

```
Browser/firefox -marionette
```

(inside the bundle). You **initialize** via

```
from marionette import Marionette
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828);
client.start_session()
```

and **load a new page** for example via

```
url='http://mozilla.org'
client.navigate(url);
```

There is a [tutorial](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html) (and further documentation) at readthedocs.