# Using TorButton add-on in Firefox (without Tor Browser Bundle)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, tor-button

For very specific reasons, I need to use the Tor in a regular Firefox browser. (I'm trying to [use Selenium WebDriver and Tor together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978074/using-selenium-webdriver-with-tor-browser-bundle), but the Tor Browser doesn't allow the WebDriver add-on, so therefore, I need to use Tor with a regular Firefox browser.)

I am using a Windows 7 machine.

**What I've tried**

- I've taken the .xpi file from the Tor Browser Bundle default profile and installed it to Firefox. However, when I run Firefox with it, I get the following screen: [image: Something Went Wrong!]
- I've downloaded the [TorButton git repository](https://git.torproject.org/torbutton.git) from the [TorButton project page](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git). However, when I try run `makexpi.sh` with Git Bash, it doesn't work because the `zip` command isn't defined on Windows machines.

Comment: check out cygwin instead of gitbash for a more fully-featured windows bash environment -- although you may need to uninstall and  reinstall git through cygwin to use it there.  It has a command-line zip package available when you install.

Comment: One more thing...git bash does have gzip; not sure if there is any difference in the command switches or parameters between that and zip, but it should be fairly straightforward to translate that zip line in the .sh script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a dumb question, but are you actually running tor?  I don't think torbutton itself does this, you need something like [Torlauncher](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking#TorLauncher) to run tor as a standalon service by itself and then you proxy your browser through it.

Edit: I should add, to simplify things you could run tor using the full tor browser bundle and then just (close the torbrowser and) set your customized firefox's proxy settings to run tor.

I should note that the Torrify HOWTO strongly recommends against this sort of setup for security reasons.  The torbrowser has had a few years of vetting and bugfixes to acheive the kind of security it has today.  If you really need webdriver though, just know in advance that you are likely sacrificing security as a tradeoff for functionality.

Comment: How would I "set my customized Firefox's proxy settings to run Tor"? And yes, I am aware of security concerns.

Comment: @joel sorry, for some reason I wAs thinking you were running a custom Firefox build -- all I meant was in Firefox options->advanced->network tab you can set socks proxy to the ports in the tor configuration.  If you have a standalone tor service running its usually port 9050 default and if you're running  tor browser bundle try 9150 instead.  Host is localhost 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Try going to the Firefox options menu and configuring Tor as a proxy. This will mean that you have to start Tor in the background but I did it with Chrome and it worked fine.

Menu > Options > Advanced > Network > Connection > Manual Proxy Configuration:

SOCKS Host is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' and port is 9150.

Make sure 'Remote DNS' is ticked

Answer (score 0):

To address your reason for this question:

> (I'm trying to use Selenium WebDriver and Tor together, but the Tor
>   Browser doesn't allow the WebDriver add-on, so therefore, I need to
>   use Tor with a regular Firefox browser.)

If you just want to remote-control the Tor Browser, have a look at [Marionette from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette). It is built into the Tor Browser (and every other current Firefox). You **enable it on the command line** by calling

```
Browser/firefox -marionette
```

(inside the bundle). You **initialize** via

```
from marionette import Marionette
client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828);
client.start_session()
```

and **load a new page** for example via

```
url='http://mozilla.org'
client.navigate(url);
```

There is a [tutorial](http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html) (and further documentation) at readthedocs.

(copy of other [answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/8693/9411)).